# Get array object in first layer of nested object array javascript functional way

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I want to go through a nested array of objects and if the condition is met, I want to return the object of the first layer the found object is in.

How can I achieve that?

My try:

```
getLayoutByTableId(tableId: number) {
   return this.layouts.map(function(layout) {
     return layout.tables.filter(function (table) {
       if (table.id === tableId) {
         return layout;
       }
     });
   })
};
```

Which returns the table object the condition is met in.

The nested object array:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":31,
      "stationId":31,
      "tables":[  
         {  
            "id":652,
            "number":"040",
            "x":1285,
            "y":527,
            "length":98,
            "breadth":69,
            "rotation":0,
            "shape":"rectangle",
            "translateX":0,
            "translateY":0,
            "masterId":null,
            "seats":4,
            "groupingActive":false
         },
         { ...
         }
      ]
   },
   { ...
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to do it with existing library functions:

```js
const data = [{id:31,stationId:31,tables:[{id:652,number:"040",x:1285,y:527,length:98,breadth:69,rotation:0,shape:"rectangle",translateX:0,translateY:0,masterId:null,seats:4,groupingActive:false},{}]},{}];

const getLayout = id => data.find(l => l && l.tables && l.tables.some(t => t.id === id));

console.log(getLayout(652));
console.log(getLayout(1111));
```